# Parents cable box caught fire, hour later half the house is out of power?

Tags: electrical, electrical-distribution

So, My dad was working on a leaking sink in a bathroom and my mom yells there is a fire. Their cable box caught fire, they put the fire out without a problem and mom called the cable company. While mom was on the phone with cable people, the house lost power but only half of the house.. My uncle is pretty handy with electric stuff and couldn't figure it out. There is no way they can afford an electrician. Any ideas please? Any thoughts are welcome

Comment: They can afford the unnecessary luxury of a monthly cable bill but not the one-time cost of calling a professional to fix a serious problem?

Comment: You need the help of a professional Electrician, and/or possibly your electrical service provider. There's a major problem that cannot be solved by folks on the internet.

Comment: Was your dad working with any corded power tools on the sink? It's possible that the increased current draw on the same branch circuit that the cable box was plugged into could have been the catalyst for what happened.

Comment: @cathode, no, that's not really possible.

Comment: What @Tester101. Plain and simple. Sorry, it's not what you want to hear, but it is completely accurate.

Comment: @iLikeDirt Don't be sanctimonious. A monthly cable bill can be as little as $30. I know of one homeowner who recently got an estimate that he needs to spend something like $10,000 to bring his house fully up to code (effectively half of it needs to be completely rewired). That's 27 ***years*** of cable bills. 

The scale is a bit different.

Comment: @Felishia Have you confirmed which circuits are now down at least? Is it the same section of the house? Does your uncle know where the wires are running? Have you considered looking at an electrical blueprint?

Comment: @cwallenpoole, I agree on not being sanctimonious, but we aren't talking about a project to remediate a known issue with well-identified and understood risks.  This is an unknown and potentially dangerous situation that needs to at least be understood quickly before somebody gets hurt, or the house burns down, which could also be quite expensive.

Comment: @JoelKeene I completely agree. I think the safest/best bet is to hire an electrician, but they will be better off if they can get the electrical blueprints or have confirmed which circuits are affected first.

The difference between "my car is making a funny noise" and "my car is making a funny noise when I break" is substantial, even if you want to have the mechanic fix it in both cases.

Comment: Have you tried contacting your electrical service provider? There might be a problem with the service, which they may fix for free.

Comment: Was the plumbing work on copper pipes ?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like they have a floating neutral in the power. If outside at the cable junction box take a look at the connectors. If they are burned or melted then it is a floating neutral and the power in the house looked for a ground which the cable lines are grounded with the house electric. This allowing the cable to get energized which can cause the fire

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like either the problems are unrelated,  or have the same cause (lightning strike or other severe surge), or the short that caused the fire drew enough current to damage the house wiring. Two out of three of those suggest there's now potential for a much more serious fire. If you don't have the knowledge to isolate the problem,  **please** hire someone who does. This is a case of "if you have to ask you shouldn't try, and even if you know what you're doing getting a pro may save your having to rip open walls for inspection. "

You can't afford *not* to have this done right.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the fire and plumbing work are unrelated. You should replace the old cable box and not plug in the burned one again! If you go to your circuit breaker box, you should be able to turn on the circuits that switched off due to the fire. If the breakers trip again, you might have a more serious electrical problem.

Comment: they reset the breaker, the cable box is unpluged but the house is still half out of power even though no breakers are tripped.